# Appending data in nested reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

My goal here is to make reducer handle nested data

[image]

Im quite confused here, as you can see on the next state object after I append an additional data, the `asia array` suddenly move outside the `data object` and data that to be inserted goes inside. The issue here is that `asia array` should not move outside the `data object`.

Here's my code:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: []
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        // Fetch speakers
        case GET_SPEAKERS_SUCCESS: {
            return Object.assign({}, state.data, {

                data: {
                    [action.payload.country]: action.payload.data
                }
            });
        }
    }

    return state;
}
```

Comment: you should be returning the whole state, not just state.data so... `Object.assign({}, state`

Comment: I did that but it overrides the content of `data object` meaning on the previous state `asia` exist but the next state, asia is replace by`thailand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
data : [...state.data,
    {     
       [action.payload.country]: action.payload.data
    }
]
```

instead of:

```
data: {
    [action.payload.country]: action.payload.data
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man, this one works :D. I wonder is this `...state.data` do is create the copy of current state?

Comment: that's the spread operator. It basically just puts the entire array into there without needing you to loop it. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator . If this answers your question, mark as appropriate thanks.

Comment: since data was an object, I think the appropriate way would be `data: {...state.data, {     
       [action.payload.country]: action.payload.data
    } }`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri data was NOT an object, look at his initial declaration `const INITIAL_STATE = {
    data: []
};`, but yes, he could also make it an object. I did not want to change it to an object because it might affect the rest of his code

Comment: Right, I had a look at the image, which suggesed data to be an object and hence the wrong deduction.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I do think that turning it into an object would probably be better overall, but since he started off with an array, it would be best to keep it as an array.